# MSSQL, List all messages but distinct sender

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, facebook

I want to list all messages of a user in a list. I was able to list all messages but I want a list of distinct sender. It similar to facebook messages view

I have this layout for the messages table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[messages](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reciever] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sender] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [posted] [datetime] NULL,
    [message] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](1) NULL
)
```

reciever and sender are foreign key of this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accounts](
    [uname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [pword] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [mname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

I tried doing this query but it doesn't work

```
SELECT [status], posted, sender, (
    SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM [messages] b
    WHERE a.sender = b.sender
) AS sender FROM [messages] a
```

The objective is to list all messages but distinct/unique sender.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and you want to get the latest record of the sender?

Comment: If you mean the latest message, yes. or just the date of latest message received.

Comment: see my answer below, *follow-up question: how are the two tables related with each other?*

Answer (score 1):

I finally get it! LOL
I just add the condition inside the WITH query block

```
WITH latestMessages
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, receiver, sender, posted, message, status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Sender
                                ORDER BY posted DESC) RN
    FROM    messages
    WHERE   receiver = 'admin'


)
SELECT  ID, receiver, sender, posted, message, status
FROM    latestMessages 
WHERE   RN = 1
```

This is much simple and quick approach rather than executing two seperate queries.

> PS: How to mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH latestMessages
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, receiver, sender, posted, message, status,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Sender
                                ORDER BY posted DESC) RN
    FROM    messages
)
SELECT  ID, receiver, sender, posted, message, status
FROM    latestMessages 
WHERE   RN = 1
```

Comment: It works but it only shows a single receiver, it does not include other users.

For your follow up question,
I have this sample query
SELECT * FROM messages a
INNER JOIN accounts b ON a.sender = b.uname
INNER JOIN accounts c ON a.receiver = c.uname

Comment: can give sample records with desired result?

Comment: Its just that I need to add a condition where in I can choose a specific reciever. Here are the sample records: http://www.mediafire.com/?rzhttyrl7c7mz36
using that records, it only shows messages for officer.

Comment: i guess you're pinoy based on your sample records `:D` anyway what will be the output then?

Comment: yes:) btw, field values goes this way, {reciever, sender, posted, status}
{officer,admin,2012-12-22,23:37:05.000,u}
{officer,2099999,2012-12-20,15:43:19.000,u}
{officer,2090808,2012-12-20,15:39:33.000,u}
{2090808,2099999,2012-12-20,15:20:07.000,u}
{admin,2090808,2012-12-20,15:36:27.000,u}
{admin,2099999,2012-12-20,15:20:22.000,u}

Comment: Btw, I can't understand how your first answer works.  How do call that procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. 
What I did was list all messages of the recipient

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM messages WHERE receiver = 'someuser'
```

Then get the recent message of the receiver

```
SELECT TOP (1) message, posted FROM messages WHERE receiver = 'someuser' AND sender = 'anotheruser' ORDER BY posted DESC
```

I did it by using some functions of the programming language I use, which was .NET